# Django and slow migrations: how to quickly get an empty database?

Tags: python, mysql, django, testing, database-migration

I have a Django 1.8 codebase with 14 apps and ~90 tables. Most apps have 1-2 migrations.

I noticed that most of the time spent running a test suite is spent on applying migrations. It may take >5 minutes to apply all migrations to an empty database.

It takes 1-2 seconds to create the database and import an SQL dump into it to achieve the same database state, though.

We are *not* using the standard `manage.py test` approach, so using `--keepdb` is likely *not an option* for me. (And even it it was, I'd have to pay the price of the migrations at least once per run.)

What I'm looking for is a way to create an empty database according to the latest models definitions. For instance, making an initial migration *as if all other migrations don't exist* would have the right effect.

Is there a known way to achieve this? Or, is there an alternative well-known approach to the problem of migrations taking a long time during tests?

Comment: I read this a while back. It should speed things up A LOT! (if youre using postgres) http://tech.marksblogg.com/test-django-on-ram-drive.html Only use it for tests please! Don't be that guy that shot him/her self in the foot

Answer (score 8):

There is a nice app called django-test-without-migrations https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-test-without-migrations/. It does just what you want: creates database using latest models definitions.

After installation and configuration (which is very simple) you just run

```
python manage.py test --nomigrations
```

or

```
python manage.py test -n
```

And it simply works.